# ASP.NET page keeps failling unless I make minimal change to web service file

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, class

OK here's a weird one.

My ASP.NET application (a wallboard application that shows employee information, corporate news, etc) includes, among other things, a bunch of .NET web pages and a web service VB file, which contains some functions (update table, retrieve users, etc).

Every now and then, the application crashes or fails to load UNLESS I make a minimal change to the web services file (such as adding a space at the bottom, or cutting a piece of code and undoing the cut). For instance, when it crashes or something, i can open this web service vb file, add space somewhere, save the file, then the app works fine!

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? It makes no sense to me why it keeps crashing and I have to keep going to that VB file to make a miniscule, useless change and save it each time!

Comment: What type of crash? What is error message, stacktrace?

Comment: Well, the app is a wallboard that uses a JQuery slideshow plugin to loop through different DIVs, each one containing content from a different ASP page. When the 'crash' occurs, the DIVs become blank. After I modify the VB file and upload it, the DIVs show content again. So by 'crash', I mean the DIV content not showing up.

Comment: Googling for solutions, I saw this http://forums.asp.net/t/986130.aspx/1?Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+App_Web+ with loads of people having the same issue, and there were various suggestions including installing a hotfix, adding "batch='true'" to the <compilation...> tag in web.config, clearing the ASP.NET temp files folder, and more. I haven't tried any of them yet. I'll do so when the issue arises again.

Answer (score 1):

You have some serious bug in your code. There must be some sort of memory leak or something, because after you make changes to config file IIS will detect that and automatically restarts app pool. So it means that over time leak accumulates and only restarting/freeing w3wp.exe process solves it, but only temporarily.

**Update**

- You may have bug in JavaScript.
- Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) tool and look at what client is sending. Maybe there is server error during Ajax call.
- check Windows EventLog
- write some error handling code on server side - Global.asax Error handler etc

Comment: Thanks, Tomas. What's the (VB) code for stopping/clearing memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before as well.

The source of my problem was a syntax error that wasn't being detected. In my case, it was the closing `}` tag to my class that was missing.

Look over your page carefully for bad syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Making a change to any source file or the web.config will cause the application to recompile and recycle the application pool.  I would check the windows logs or IIS logs for why your application is crashing in the first place.  The recycle of the application pool will allow it to start clean, but my guess is you have a memory leak somewhere that is causing it to die after it runs for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Bahri. Looking at the IIS logs shows lots of "Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_ga3taeio, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.", whatever that means. I searched google for explanations of that error, but no luck

Comment: All of the App_Web_????? names are autogenerated assemblies from your web application.  When you use xcopy deployment for an ASP.Net application, it is these assemblies that get run.  I suggest using the build and deploy tools that do not copy the .vb/.cs files to the web application directory.  All of your assemblies should be in the /bin directory of your web application, and you then would have none of these oddly named assemblies.  Another thing you can do is move code out of your web application into a library assembly, which will actually compile the code before your web is built.

Comment: Thanks, Bahri. I normally use Visual Studio's "Website -> Copy Web Site..." menu option to upload the files. I'll look into using build/deploy tools (where're they??). Not sure how it's done, though. Thanks.

Comment: Right click on the Web project in Visual Studio, and click Publish Web Site.  Select the path to deploy the files.  This will compile all of the code and not copy the source files.

Comment: Cool stuff. Thanks. Though do I have to publish the entire site everytime I make a small change (such as fixing a typo)?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that IIS monitors the files which make up the site.  If one of those files is changed, IIS automatically restarts the site.  The web.config file is the most common example of a file that might change in production, but I believe other files (like a .vb source file) could trigger it as well.

When the app crashes, can you kill all the wp3.exe processes (or asp worker processes if you're on an older IIS version), and restart the site - does that resolve the problems?  If so, that's an indicator that "restarting IIS" is what actually gets your site working again; you just happen to be triggering it by making a change to a file.